# Javascript - browse between screens

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a web page with many sections, and I navigate between these sections using querystring. I need to create a loop to browse between these screens from time to time. I tried to use carousel, but it did not work for what I need. Does anyone have any ideia how do this?

Ps: I'm using asp.net with c#, but thought do this using javascript

Comment: without seeing any code it's hard to know what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: " create a loop to browse between these screens ". Not really sure what this means. A more detailed explanation and some sample code of what's not working would make this a lot clearer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more guidance on creating a good question which people can answer.